# TempData is null after redirection

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, tempdata

I want use TempData to pass messages between Test1 and Test2 actions but when I read tempdata's key on Test2's action the value on TempData key is null. I read the documentation about TempData on MDSN this is what it say:

> Represents a set of data that persists only from one request to the
>   next.

My code is that:

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    public const string TEMP_DATA_KEY = "TEST";
    public IActionResult Test1()
    {
        TempData[TEMP_DATA_KEY] = "ciao";
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Test2));
    }
    public IActionResult Test2()
    {
        TempData.TryGetValue(TEMP_DATA_KEY, out object saluto);
        return View();
    }
}
```

What is wrong, Test1 is first request Test2 is next request why TempData is null?

Thank you regards

Comment: Your code works fine as is. What are you expecting to do with your saluto object? If you want to display it on the View of Test2 you will need to pass it towards the View as well => return View(saluto);  Check your code while debugging and you see that the saluto object is instantiated with the expected content of "ciao"

Comment: I try this code on my solution and it did not work, variable saluto is null my solution is develop on aspnet core 2.2

Comment: Can you add your corresponding View into the question?

Comment: Is there any demo to reproduce your issue? Check web browser debug network tab, to see whether there is any cookies contains `TEST`

Comment: @TaoZhou, sorry  i can not pubblish my solution, in network tab there is not any cookie

Answer (score 0):

In your controller update the Test2 Action as noted below:

```
    public const string TEMP_DATA_KEY = "TEST";
    public IActionResult Test1()
    {
        TempData[TEMP_DATA_KEY] = "ciao";
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Test2));
    }
    public IActionResult Test2()
    {
        TempData.TryGetValue(TEMP_DATA_KEY, out object saluto);
        return View(saluto);
    }
```

Update your View (Test2.cshtml) as shown below.

```
@model string
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Test2";
}

<h1>@Model</h1>
```

This wil show the value you've added in Test1 into your TempData in the h1 tag on the Test2 View.